# Map column names if data is same in two dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, names

I have two pandas dataframes

df1 = A B C
      1 2 3
      2 3 4 
      3 4 5

df2 = X Y Z
      1 2 3
      2 3 4 
      3 4 5 
I need to map based on data If data is same then map column names`enter code here`
Output = col1 col2
          A     X
          B     Y
          C     Z

Comment: please provide an illustration that shows your input and output. The current output format in your question is hard to follow. If it should be in a table format then show it in a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot find any built-in function to support this, hence simply loop over all columns:

```
pairs = []
for col1 in df1.columns:
    for col2 in df2.columns:
        if df1[col1].equals(df2[col2]):
            pairs.append((col1, col2))

output = pandas.DataFrame(pairs, columns=['col1', 'col2'])
```

Comment: Thanks but those I have thousands of columns and they are not in order

Comment: What do you mean "not in order"? The order of columns should not matter. The code loops over all combination of columns

Comment: Thanks it worked in pandas,How Can I implement this in SAS